# How can I select the row until met specific condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image: This is a Table]

when I count all trips in 2015 I got about 340,000 trips

```
SELECT COUNT(trip_id) AS number_of_trips
FROM bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015
```

but now I want to select the minimum amount of station that makes the overall trip amount reach over 320,000

```
SELECT
    start_station_id AS station_id,
    COUNT(trip_id) AS number_of_trips
FROM
    bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
WHERE
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015 
    AND SUM(number_of_trips)>=320000
GROUP BY
    station_id
ORDER BY
    number_of_trips DESC
```

something like this but it doesn't work or even subquery on an inner join

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: From the first query I count the overall trip and it shows ~340,000 trips
from 340k trips it could be from station no.1 = 20000, no.2 = 30,000, no.3 =  25000 ..... until the overall sum 340k

but I want to query the minimum list of station that makes the overall trip reach 320k (DESC)
some poor station that generates trip with poor amount should be removed

Comment: To be more visualized 
a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
e = 1
f =1
overall count is 7
but I want the until the count is 5
so i want to get
a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
only this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now I want to select the minimum amount of station that makes the overall trip amount reach over 320,000

You would get the list of stations using a cumulative sum and then filter:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT start_station_id AS station_id,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as running_cnt
      FROM bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
      WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015 
      GROUP BY 1
     ) s
WHERE running_cnt - cnt < 320000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move SUM/COUNT condition into Having, like this :

```
    SELECT start_station_id AS station_id, COUNT(trip_id) AS number_of_trips
    FROM bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015
    GROUP BY station_id having COUNT(trip_id)>=320000
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: it show: This query returned no results.
I want to select minimum amount of station that make the overall trip_id over 320,000 
from you query I think it try to find the the station that having trip count more than 320k